# Which babel-* package should I include in webpack to support IE11

Tags: npm, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, babel-polyfill

I want to support IE11 (e.g. [`NodeList.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) ) in my project using babel inside webpack, but I find it  confusing to select the right babel package.

Current packages are:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
"webpack": "^4.41.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
```

Possible candiates are:

- The packages `core-js/stable` and `regenerator-runtime/runtime` (as proposed in [`@babel/polyfill`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) page)
- [`@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime)
- [`@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-regenerator)
- [`@babel/runtime`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-runtime)

my current `webpack.config`

```js
             options: {
                compact: false, 
                presets:
                  [["@babel/env", {//env preset
                    "targets": {
                      "browsers": ["last 2 Chrome versions", "last 2 Firefox versions", "Explorer >= 11"]
                    }
                  }]]
              }
```

Can someone explain what each of these package does and what package/configuration should I include in order for IE11 to be able to support `NodeList.forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

[core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) (installed by `@babel/polyfill`) implements `NodeList.prototype.forEach()` as polyfill. See [this issue](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/329).

So if you import `core-js/stable` as suggested in the [Babel documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage#polyfill), `NodeList.prototype.forEach()` will be implemented if it doesn't already exist.

```js
import "core-js/stable";
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What other packages used for?